# How can I prove that this language is context free?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, context-free-grammar

How can I prove that this language is context free, where $A$ and $B$ are regular languages ?
$$L= \left \{ wx\mid w\in A,  x\in B \right \}$$

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Do you mean "Show that the language $\{w x \mid w \in A, x \in B \}$ is context-free, where $A$ and $B$ are regular languages"?

Comment: Yes. Im sorry, my english is not very good. :( Can you help me?

Comment: In fact $L$ is regular. You can prove this either by showing how to combine regular expressions for $A$ and $B$ to get a regular expression for $L$ or by showing how to combine DFAs for $A$ and $B$ to get a DFA for $L$.

Comment: Thank you! :)))